# How to structure types of people in a database

Tags: database-design

I'm looking for the best approach to this database design issue.  I think I found something that works fine, but I don't know if it is the best approach.  I'm using CakePHP if that means anything to you.

My database is made for music lessons.  I have all people whether they be parents, students, teachers, administrators or anyone else in a table called people outlined below:

```
People
id first_name last_name email created modified
```

Now the issue I am starting to have is how to identify one person as a teacher, student parent etc.  It makes sense to me to have a separate table for each group.  For example

```
Teachers
id person_id

Students
id person_id

Payers
id person_id
```

This way theoretically a teacher could also be a student. A "payer", the person paying for lessons, could also be a student and the list goes on.

Now I also need to know the relationship between a person and a student.  So I would have a separate table like this:

```
Relationships:
id person_id student_id type
```

"type" could be mother, father, legal guardian, care taker, aunt, grandmother etc.  This design makes sense to me, but at the same time it seems like quite a bit of work and tables to describe something that seems like it should be easier to describe.  Is there a better way to do this?  I keep second guessing myself and thinking having a completely new table just to label a person as a student or teacher or what not seems overkill somehow.

Comment: Do you need different kinds of relationships for different kinds of people involved in them, or just one generic kind is enough? For example, is there anything special about relationship between teacher and student compared to relationship between say, parent and student?

Comment: I need different relationships.  It's just so I know who people are.  I need to know when I contact someone that they are the Mom or Grandma or just the person that is going to pay for the lessons.  I wouldn't need an extra table to explain the relationships for parents or grandparents etc.  I only need to know who the payer and the student are for actual calculations.  All other relationships would be defined in the "relationships" table which wouldn't need any calculations and would just be for contacting people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have described a classic sub-typing scenario, where `PERSON` is your supertype and you have defined subtypes including: `STUDENT`, `TEACHER`, `PARENT` (really guardian), and presumably other types as well, such as employees, etc.

Typically when you use this type of subtyping model, it's because the various subtypes have their own distinct *predicates*, i.e. attributes or relationships.

To model your relationships, you need to decide what is important from a business rule perspective and what is worth doing to impose these business rules in your schema.  If you want or need to be picky, you might decide to have a `GUARDIAN_RELATIONSHIP` table that is an intersection between your `PARENT` and `STUDENT` tables.  This would have FK's to each of the person subtypes in question as well as your relationship type flag/code/description.

Alternatively, you could just have a single `PERSONAL_RELATIONSHIP` table which is an intersection between two `PERSON` records.  You could also put a relationship type code here too.  This approach is much looser but possibly easier to maintain.  In the end it depends on how many types of relationships you need to track and how central they are to your business rules.

Comment: How would I make the intersection between the personal_relationship table and two person records?  I can't have person_id twice in the personal relationship table...  It sounds like the best way, but I'm confused about how to go about it.

Comment: @Brian - You can easily have `person_id` twice, you just have to give each column a different name, like `first_person_id`, `second_person_id`.  Use your FK constraint to link each FK to `PERSON.person_id`.  This shouldn't be a problem unless there is some constraint in CakePHP which requires so-called "natural joins" (joining by equal column names).

Comment: @Brian You might find it interesting to look at [the reasons for sub-typing](https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20ERwin%20Data%20Modeler%20r8-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/Methods/index.htm?toc.htm?254775.html). You'll need to decide if these reasons apply in your case.